# Sitecore Select Media only shows currently selected item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library, sitecore7.2

According to the [Sitecore 7.2 content author cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/72/content_author's_cookbook_sc72-us_letter.pdf) (page 66):

> In the **Content** pane, click **Browse** to open the **Select Media** dialog box. The **Select Media**
>   dialog box opens and displays all the items from the Media Library that is available for the image 
>   field you have chosen.

However, on my system, there is a `Media folder` showing the currently selected media item for the image. The problem is all the filter options, *My Images*, *Recently Uploaded Images*, even *All Image Files*, only show descendants of the currently selected item and itself. There doesn't seem to be a way to select a different folder or reset the Media folder, unless you close the **Select Media** window, Clear the image field and then click Browse. But Clearing the image field before Browse also resets the Tree view, making it more difficult to select siblings of the current image.

Considering my local instance (and a second vanilla install I set up for testing) behave differently than the documentation, is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: I can't reproduce this in 7.2 (rev. 140228). Do you have a datasource specified for the field in the template?

Comment: I just tested a vanilla 7.2 rev. 140228, and I cannot reproduce the issue there.  The issue does exist in 7.2 rev. 140526 (and no, I don't have a datasource specified).  It seems this is an issue introduced in either update-1 or update-2.  I guess I will take it up with Sitecore support. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I'm definitely getting this issue in a clean install of 8.1. No data sources set in the template. The view simply gets scoped to the current item, and shows no siblings. Tree view is my solve for the time being.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After submitting an issue with Sitecore support, they reported the bug and provided a patch to use for the current rev.

If anyone else has this issue, the files provided were:

```
Sitecore.Support.406359.dll
Sitecore.Support.406359.config
```

Answer (score 4):

I am able to reproduce this in Sitecore 7.2 rev 140526.  Basically from what I can tell, it is setting the "Media Folder" to the location of the selected image.  Because of this you only we the single image, it should however be setting the "Media folder" path to what you have in the Source property but isn't doing that.

Until this is resolved, i've had my content authors use the "Tree View" tab to select the image as this works just fine.  Also, made a change to the /sitecore/shell/Applications/Media/MediaBrowser/MediaBrowser.xml file to "Tree View" tab be the default selected when the dialog opens.

**Update**

Instead of modifying the actual code file, you make the TreeView the default tab via a config change.

Modify the /App_Config/Include/Sitecore.Speak.config file as follows:

```
replace the following line:

<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaDialog" />

with this one:

<override xmlControl="Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Media.MediaBrowser" with="/sitecore/client/applications/Dialogs/SelectMediaViaTreeDialog" />
```